# make multiple, composite query in oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

How can i make multiple, composite query in oracle?

for example this several queries in one step?

1

```
CREATE TABLE test (id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR2(30));
```

2

```
CREATE SEQUENCE test_sequence START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;
```

3

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_trigger
BEFORE INSERT
ON test
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT test_sequence.nextval INTO :NEW.ID FROM dual;
END;
```

4

```
INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES ('Jon');
```

5

```
INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES ('Meloun');
```

Comment: There are 0 queries here.  Are you asking how you run multiple statements inside a single script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved it by wrapping each statement in an EXECUTE IMMEDIATE command inside a PL/SQL script:

```
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE test (id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR2(30))';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE SEQUENCE test_sequence START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1';
  -- etc
END;
```

Comment: So you can execute several ddl statements in one query, without having to return to the client for every statement

Answer (score 0):

By and large DDL statements have to executed one at a time.  It is true that Oracle supports [the CREATE SCHEMA syntax](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg03sch.htm#1929), but this only permits the creation of multiple tables and/or views plus grants on them.  It doesn't include ancilliary objects such as sequences or triggers.

You could turn the two inserts into a single statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO test (name)
select  'Jon' from dual
union all
select  'Meloun' from dual
/
```

This might be more trouble than its worth, but I suppose it does give you a simple transactionality: it inserts either all the rows or none of them.